# inversify.js resolve by name

Tags: ioc-container, typescript2.0, inversifyjs

I want to create little CQRS framework for my Typescript Node.js project.

I wish to resolve class by it's name from inversify.js container.
I need something like that:

```
let x = container.get("Foo");
```

where Foo is regular class and container is Container object from inversify.js.

Is it possible to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following:

```
import { Container, injectable } from "inversify";

@injectable()
class Foo {
    // ...
}

const container = new Container();
container.bind(Foo).toSelf();

const foo = container.get(Foo);
```

Or (if foo is the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)):

```
import { Container, injectable } from "inversify";

@injectable()
class Foo {
    // ...
}

const container = new Container();
const foo = container.resolve(Foo);
```